# DAG of Case Classes scala

Tags: scala, types, case-class

I'm new to Scala and have several classes that implement the same trait, and I want the fields on each class be related to each other via a DAG.

To be concrete, let's say the class fields are arranged like this:

```
      ---A.version---
      |             |
      V             V
   B1.version   B2.version
      |             |
      -->C.version<--
```

And we have code like this:

```scala
trait Versioned {
  val version: String = "1.0"
}

case class A() extends Versioned

case class B1() extends Versioned {
  override def version: String = "1.1"
}

case class B2() extends Versioned

case class C() extends Versioned
```

Data of type `A` and `B2` should have `version = "1.0"` and data of type `B1` and `C` should have `version = "1.1"`. I'm not sure if this is best solved using companion objects, which seems a little bit verbose considering every case class will require one, or if a `parents` field (containing references to types?) on the `Versioned` trait will work.

Comment: Is the `version` a property of the *objects* (in which case it belongs in the classes, which are templates for objects), or a property of the *types* (in which case it should be somewhere more static, like the companions)? "Verbosity" is not a valid reason to choose the former over the latter.

Comment: It's a property of the type.

Comment: In that case, it is important to know what you need to do with this `version`. If it's really a property of the type, then you can't (easily) e.g. have a bunch of objects of different `version`s in a collection. What actual behavior do you want out of your DAG?

Comment: Basically the property I'm looking for is that for a given data type, I can figure out what version it should be on, given the versions of its parent types (and their parents, etc.), without writing the explicit version in every single companion object.